# Scala NullPointerException during initialization

Tags: scala, gatling

Consider the following case (this is a simplified version of what I have. The *numberOfScenarios* is the most important variable here: I usually use a hardcoded number instead of it, but I'm trying to see if it's possible to calculate the value):

```
object ScenarioHelpers {
    val identifierList = (1 to Scenarios.numberOfScenarios).toArray
    val concurrentIdentifierQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue[Int](identifierList.toSeq)
}

abstract class AbstractScenario {
    val identifier = ScenarioHelpers.concurrentIdentifierQueue.poll()
}

object Test1 extends AbstractScenario {
    val scenario1 = scenario("test scenario 1").exec(/..steps../)
}

object Test2 extends AbstractScenario {
    val scenario2 = scenario("test scenario 2").exec(/..steps../)
}

object Scenarios {
    val scenarios = List(Test1.scenario1, Test2.scenario2)
    val numberOfScenarios = scenarios.length
}

object TestPreparation {
    val feeder = ScenarioHelpers.identifierList.map(n => Map("counter" -> n))
    val prepScenario = scenario("test preparation")
        .feed(feeder)
        .exec(/..steps../)
}
```

Not sure if it matters, but the simulation starts with executing the TestPreparation.prepScenario.

I see that this code contains a circular dependency which makes this case impossible in and of itself. But I get a NullPointerException on the line in AbstractScenario where *identifier* is being initialized.

I don't fully understand all this, but I think it has something to do with the vals being simply declared at first and the initialization does not happen until later. So when *identifier* is being initialized, the *concurrentIdentifierQueue* is not yet initialized and is therefore null.

I'm just trying to understand the reasons behind the NullPointerException and also if there's any way to get this working with minimal changes? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

NPEs during trait initialization is a very common problem. 
The most robust way to resolve it is avoiding implementation inheritance at all.

if it is not possible for some reasons you can mark problematic fields `lazy val` or `def` instead of `val`.

Comment: Yeah that usually works I guess, but the feeder wants everything right now and doesn't care about defs and lazy vals.

Answer (score 1):

You answered that yourself:

> I see that this code contains a circular dependency which makes this case impossible in and of itself. But I get a NullPointerException on the line in AbstractScenario where identifier is being initialized.

- `val feeder = ScenarioHelpers.identifierList...` calls ScenarioHelpers initialization
- `val identifierList = (1 to Scenarios.numberOfScenarios).toArray` calls `Scenarios` initialization
- `val scenarios = List(Test1.scenario1, Test2.scenario2)` calls `Test1` inicialization including `AbstractScenario`
- Here `val identifier = ScenarioHelpers.concurrentIdentifierQueue.poll()`  `ScenarioHelpers` is still initializing and `identifierList` is null.

You have to get `numberOfScenarios` in noncyclic way. Personally I would remove `identifierList` and assign identifier other way - incrementing counter or so.

Comment: OK thank you, I didn't have to remove identifierList, but you gave me an idea for the counter and I replaced the concurrent queue with an AtomicInteger.